# Create Circular Launcher Icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, assets, android-launcher

I am trying to create circular launcher icons in Android Studio 2.2 but they keep coming out square. Has anyone else encountered this? Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8):

After clicking `Next` you should get circular launcher icon.

Previews might be misleading as they have background as the icon.

After all, if you won't get what you expect, try: https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Hope it will help

Comment: I don't get a circular icon. They come out square.

Comment: @Firemarble, It might be AndroidStudio bug, try to use `Android Asset Studio`instead  to generate circular launcher

Comment: This bug still exists.

Comment: its not a bug...there is a scroll right next to Name column

Comment: I had the same problem with the Android Studio Image Asset option. With the Android Asset Studio (see link from piotrek1543) I was able to create the round icons. I downloaded them and added them manually to the mipmap-folder.

Comment: @anshulkatta - Thank you! I did not see the scroll bar at first.

Answer (score 5):

Set the project structure to Android
For app module :- 
1. Select app-> res
2. Right click on res folder, click on Image Asset
3. In Legacy tab set the shape to Circle

For wear module :- 
1. Select wear-> res
2. Right click on res folder, click on Image Asset
3. In Legacy tab set the shape to Circle

Answer (score 1):

Go to under "File > New > Asset Studio", then look for Foreground, Background, Legacy.
Click on Legacy and
choose "circle" from the drop-down menu under "shape".