# Asset Studio in Android Studio; Square not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, icons, android-icons

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.1 with Mac OS 10.11.6.

I'm adding the ic_launcher-icon with control click>New>Image Asset. I usually take `Shape: Square`. That makes the corners rounded like an iOS icon.

But suddenly it doesn't work. It looks like this:
[image: Square]

Also trying to use `Shape: Circle` doesn't work. It's still as before. But you can see a shadow of a circle on the icon:
[image]

When running the app the icon is as in the Asset Studio. That means it's not only a worn Asset Studio display.

I also removed Android Studio with AppCleaner and reinstalled it, but without success.

Does anybody know what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to: [Create Circular Launcher Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621163/create-circular-launcher-icon) it might be `Android Studio` bug, try to use Android Asset Studio instead to generate circular launcher

Android Asset Studio:  https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Hope it will help

Comment: Android Asset Studio could work. But how can I integrate the icons in my app? Will I have to copy every size in the right folder manually?

Comment: nope. it generates folder `res` with exact subfolders like `mipmap-hdpi`, so you need to merge your existing `res` folder with the generated ones. Pretty simple and effective

Answer (score -1):

So the observation I just had on the Android Studio Image Asset Studio, the shape you are talking about is just for the background image. That is, if you have a .png image with transparent background, you can use this shape option to create your icon with custom background of desired shape and color. But if your image is beyond the scope of the background shape, then it will be useless. Like in your case, since your image is full square, the background doesn't make sense.

> In short, the shape option is for background but not for image