# How to change the app launcher icon from square shape to circular shape in android studio

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am new to android.I developed an android application.It is working fine,but problem is how to change my app launcher icon to circular shape by default app icon getting square shape.

Here is my code

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/image"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/image"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39621163/create-circular-launcher-icon


use here any image to your app icon and select shape here.

Answer (score -1):

Change you `android:icon=""` to round icon that you want and **uninstall** your previously installed Application from device and re-install Application.

```
android:icon="@drawable/round_image"
```

Here `round_image` should be present in your **drawable** folder.

> Note : Uninstalling previously installed **Application** is **necessary**.